# JavaScript adding "·" character to endline

Tags: javascript, python, automated-tests

So I'm trying to run a tests.js for a python code I've written, everything seems fine however at the end of each line ("\n" character), the tests.js file is appending a  "·" character. The file internally uses the toString() method to convert the python output to a string and then compares it with the expected string using toEqual().

My code:

```
def print_help():
    print("""Usage :-
$ ./task add 2 hello world    # Add a new item with priority 2 and text "hello world" to the list
$ ./task ls                   # Show incomplete priority list items sorted by priority in ascending order
$ ./task del INDEX            # Delete the incomplete item with the given index
$ ./task done INDEX           # Mark the incomplete item with the given index as complete
$ ./task help                 # Show usage
$ ./task report               # Statistics""", end="")
```

The output:
[image: error]

The tests.js code:

```
test("prints help", () => {
  let received = execSync(tasksTxtCli("help")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(usage));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're using for your output in Node.js, but it's likely that this isn't actually a middle dot character, but an otherwise unprintable character by your terminal emulator.

In other words, what you're seeing isn't *really* there.  It's just that *something* is there.

I expect that this is a difference between `\r\n` and `\n` for newline characters.  Your comparison string probably doesn't have `\r\n`, but the Python output probably does.

If you want to be really sure as to what it is, pipe your Python output to a file and open it up with a hex editor.  Or even, just don't convert to a string and use `console.log()` (or `util.inspect()`) to see a hex representation of the binary output.

Comment: Yes you're right. I checked the output using a hex editor and it is indeed a carriage return. But now the question is: How do I get rid of that? I cannot edit the test.js file as I'm supposed to do edits within the python file only.

Comment: @AyamDobhal I think your tests are too strict.  But, if you insist on checking this output with automated testing, I think your tests should support either line ending out of your Python application.  In any case, when you're editing this Python file, use a text editor that allows you change line endings.  If you're using VSCode for example, you can change it on the bottom right of the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

As per my solution modify your code as:

```
def print_help():
    help="""Usage :-
$ ./task add 2 hello world    # Add a new item with priority 2 and text "hello world" to the list
$ ./task ls                   # Show incomplete priority list items sorted by priority in ascending order
$ ./task del INDEX            # Delete the incomplete item with the given index
$ ./task done INDEX           # Mark the incomplete item with the given index as complete
$ ./task help                 # Show usage
$ ./task report               # Statistics"""
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(help.encode('utf8'))
```

In this way , the dot(.) won't appear on command line.
Reference: https://github.com/nseadlc-2020/package-todo-cli-task/issues/12